# Hide and Show button inside a for-loop of template in Alpine.js and Django

Tags: django, alpine.js

Hide and Show button inside a for-loop of template in Alpine.js and Django.

conversion of django if else condition template to Alpine.js,

How do we convert this code inside a for-loop condition on template using Alpine.js

```
{% if employee.allow_programme_membership_expiry %}
    <a href="{% url 'buyer:programme-membership-expiry' employee.buyer_id employee.id %}">
        {% svg_icon "Change-Expiry" "w-6 h-6 dui-stroke-primary" None "Change Expiry" %}
    </a>
{% endif %}
```